# Calling class level variables using "@pytest.mark.parametrize" fixture

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I'm trying to iterate a pytest test over a list of values which i generate inside another method in the test class.

The problem is that i get:
 ***"@pytest.mark.parametrize("number",TestScratch.list_testing)
NameError: name 'TestScratch' is not defined"*** error when i try to run.I know for a fact that when i pass the list as a hard coded list i.e *[0,3,54,90]* it works.
Below is my code :

```
class TestScratch(object):

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.list_testing = []

    @classmethod
    def setup_method(cls):
        pass


    def test_populate_list(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.list_testing.append(i)

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("number",TestScratch.list_testing)
    def test_pytest_param(self, number):
        assert type(number) == int

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls):
        '''
        pass
        '''
```

I also tried self.**class**.list_testing
but i get the same error

**Environment details:**

Python: 3.6.8

Pytest: 5.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the class in the class definition. As the decorator is read at import time, e. g. while loading the class definition, and not at runtime, the class is not known at this point. You have to define the list outside the class instead:

```
import pytest

def populate_list():
    test_list = []
    for i in range(100):
        test_list.append(i)
    return test_list


list_testing = populate_list()


class TestScratch:
    def test_populate_list(self):
        # this will fail if list_testing could not be populated
        assert len(list_testing) > 50

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("number", list_testing)
    def test_pytest_param(self, number):
        # this will be skipped if list_testing could not be populated
        assert type(number) == int
```

Any parameter you use in a decorator is read only once at load time, so trying to intialize it at runtime won't work. For example [here](https://medium.com/opsops/deepdive-into-pytest-parametrization-cb21665c05b9) you can find an explanation how parametrization works and why it is not possible to add parameters at runtime.

Comment: Thanks solved the problem. Though another issue i seem to be facing is that 'test_pytest_param' test method is not iterating over the items in the list:


`code

scratch.py::TestScratch::test_populate_list PASSED                                                                                                                

scratch.py::TestScratch::test_pytest_param[number0] SKIPPED

`

Comment: correct [https://pastebin.com/1Q86d2Gu]
also i noticed that if i populate the list outside the class it works, the problem is when i populate the list inside one of the test methods , which is unfortunately what i must do since i need to run a test on the source of the list.

Comment: correct link: https:// paste.ofcode.org/ N6JNrZgmnS9rwKQ7KnK2T9

Comment: Ah ok, now I see it. You still populate the list at runtime - as I wrote, this will not work. It must be populated at load time, so you can't do this inside a method or function.

Comment: So basically you're saying : "You're stuck buddy' ?

Comment: Well, if you can't populate the list outside the class (I don't know your real code - in the given example you certainly can, as shown in the answer), then yes, you can't use `parametrize`.

Comment: the example is pretty much close to my code except i don't use a loop but parse a file to the list

Comment: So, can't you do that outside of the test class?

Comment: No, it's a series of dependent tests . each one generating data for the next one

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer a bit to make it clearer. Generally, tests shouldn't depend on each other, though I don't know your specific setup. If you can't refactor it accordingly, you just have to iterate over the test data inside a single test.

Comment: That's what i've trying to avoid , this was the way it was previously implemented, i'm trying to refactor it so each element in the list will have it's own test. This is required so i will have a more detailed report on each element.

Comment: If your test data is only known at runtime, you are stuck indeed, and not knowing your actual code I can't say if it is possible to change that - sorry.